# Count words in a string filled by user

Tags: ios, swift

As the title says, I want to count the words in a string, which is filled by the user. For that purpose, I will simplify it a little and I will count the white spaces in the string, store the value in an other variable and the print that new variable.

The code I am using is the following:

```
import UIKit

class TransViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var trad_text: UITextView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    trad_text!.layer.borderWidth = 1
    trad_text!.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    trad_text!.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red:0.22, green:0.26, blue:0.39, alpha:1.0).cgColor
}



override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    let text = trad_text.text

    let num_words = text?.characters.split(separator: " ").map(String.init)
    print(num_words)
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

But it does not print any number of words. Can someone find why this code gives the error?

Thank you for your time

Comment: Unrelated to your error but why are you doing this in `viewDidLoad`? Your view controller isn't even visible yet so how can you be processing the text entered by the user?

Comment: This error has nothing to do with the code snippet you pasted.

Comment: Yeah the error is unrelated. Please give us the code that actually tries to fetch the asset info.

Comment: Thank you answer. It is true, it makes no sense to put it in viewDidLoad. How would you do it to get the text after the user introduces it?

Comment: Please supply sufficient code so that the problem can be reproduced.

Comment: What are you doing? `didReceiveMemoryWarning` will (should) _never_ be called, so your code will never run.

Comment: Yeah, moving the code from `viewDidLoad` to `didReceiveMemoryWarning` is a giant step in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally did it with the following code, maybe it will be useful to someone:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class TransViewController: UIViewController {

final class Shared {
    static let shared = Shared() //lazy init, and it only runs once

    var stringValue : String!
    var num_words : Int!
    var boolValue   : Bool!
}

@IBOutlet var trad_text: UITextView!
@IBOutlet var buttonTrad: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var labelsitoh: UILabel!

@IBAction func butCalc(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    let text = trad_text.text

    let num_words =  (text?.components(separatedBy: " ").count)!-1

    Shared.shared.num_words = num_words
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    trad_text!.layer.borderWidth = 1
    trad_text!.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    trad_text!.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red:0.22, green:0.26, blue:0.39, alpha:1.0).cgColor
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
var string = "first second third"
let count = string.components(separatedBy: .whitespaces).count
```

Count equal `3` for this case.

Comment: In what way does this address the issue in the question?

Comment: This code solves main goal - Count words in a string

Comment: This code solves main goal - Count words in a string

Comment: The posted code already does that. The question isn't asking how to count words. The question is asking about the error.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but what I am looking for i to count the words when a textView is filled